# LastPass + Tor = Anonymous?

Tags: anonymity

**could you give me your idea whether using Tor in conjunction with
the password manager LastPass would compromise my anonymity?**

LastPass stores passwords on their servers. I do not know how often
it needs to be accessed. Once per browser session (one could switch
to a new Tor identity afterwards) or before every login to a site.
https://lastpass.com/how-it-works/

I am afraid using the LastPass account would allow adversaries to create
a profile of mine then.

Any ideas on that?

I really tried hard to install any other password manager with browser
extension on my Linux. Only LastPass works. And I really need a tool
to manage my login data.

Comment: Thanks, for the info meee and MyNameIsBoring! I really tried hard to find (/install) any offline password
manager with browser integration. I would have loved to use KeePass
but was unable to get it running on my Debian. **Any suggestions for an offline password manger with a good browser
integration usable under Linux?** THX!
-Thor

Comment: For Windows users there is an offline solution directly from LastPass which is [LastApp](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/lastpass-for-applications/). It is only for premium members and seems to be an early project.

Comment: "Needing a password manager means you are logging frequently/randomly to your favorite websites. This is a factor that acts against your anonymity."
Many people have to struggle to shift between private interactions online and those that may unfortunately not be very private. When I do a search for online privacy and password manager, it means I want to understand the relationship between going to websites like credit card sites where online security is an issue, and want to maximize online privacy as well, or at least understand the dilemmas and try to selectively optimize one or the other. C

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you created or ever used this service without Tor. Your email address is another identifier, that is kept over Tor sessions. It might make sense to use an offline password manager ([DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Products_and_Tools/Password_Tools/) has a list) or a tool like [PasswordMaker](http://www.passwordmaker.org/) instead, so you don't need any form of account that could be used to tack you.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://keepass.info/ with the http://keefox.org/ FireFox plugin.  The password database is stored locally.

Answer (score 2):

You wanted a suggestion for Password Manager for GNU/Linux.
Try [KeepassX](https://www.keepassx.org/), it's the GNU/Linux port of Keepass that can work without Mono installed.
It can perform `autotype` username and password in your browser, if that's what you mean by "browser integration" without the need for external addon/plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Needing a password manager means you are logging frequently/randomly to your favorite websites. This is a factor that acts against your anonymity.