# How to run Lastpass in Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Can someone please explain how to get Lastpass to run in Tor, I need on occasions to access some sites that I have passwords which are impossible to remember.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work for you? Its a browser plugin, so you install it in the tor browser bundle (all though i would not recommend it). Mozilla sync can also be used. Or a program like keepass / keepassx. I use keepass and keep the database for my self. Or mozilla sync set up on my own server.

Comment: I have installed the plugin, but nothing happens when I enter the master password.

Comment: While there are some [concern and discussion over security issues on using LastPass over Tor Browser Bundle](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=55189), it is possible to [disable Tor Access authentication](https://lastpass.com/disablemultifactor.php?multifactortype=tor) as a reasonable compromise (at least in my case) between security and convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Great Question!

Usually what works for me is opening LastPass in a different browser and simply copying/pasting the passwords I need.

For example, I'll have my Tor window up, but at the same time, I'll open up a Chrome window with the LastPass extension. Then, I'll just copy and paste each password I need from the Chrome window to the Tor window. It works like a charm.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Not really an answer to "How to run Lastpass through Tor" but I'm upvoting it because I believe that this is a better alternative than actually running Lastpass through Tor.

Comment: This is a pretty bad solution. If you have a clipboard manager that stores the last 100 clips then your password will end up on disk in plain text, and if you backup your computer, it will end up in your backup where it might be difficult to delete and very easy to overlook the problem.

Comment: And even if you don't use a clipboard manager you might, by mistake backup your regular clipboard content to your backup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd heard that if you have other programs like browsers that communicate with the web open at the same time, then these might be ‘leaky’ and possibly divulge information about your system, not sure if it's location, or something else?

Because of this, I copy & paste the details into **notepad**; then close the browsers & cloud sync program or anything that's still regularly communicating with the net; in addition, I use a VPN. Don't know if I need to take other security precautions.

This might sound like overkill, but as I'm not too knowledgeable about these things, I didn't want to take that chance. Personally, I'd love to be able to use LastPass on Tor!

K!

Answer (score 0):

In the top menu, select **Tools -> Add-ons** to get to Add-ons manager.

Search for '**Lastpass**' in the searchbox in top right corner, it takes you to Firefox Lastpass Add-on page. Click **Add to Firefox** button and Lastpass will be installed as add-on to your Tor browser.

Though I need to mention, question about anonymity is still open: [LastPass + Tor = Anonymous?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/lastpass-tor-anonymous?newreg=a23cb23573ba4e35bb9a270418ae4446)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't specifically answer your question, but I strongly discourage using Last Pass or for that matter any Firefox addon (plugins/extension) while using the Tor browser (which the Tor project also says). The Tor Project explains that addons can connect to the internet insecurely and can potentially leak your IP address on the internet. The whole point of using Tor is to be anonymous. If you are using websites that require passwords in Tor, just use another application like notepad to store your passwords just as Kelvin H stated. Its a more secure and reliable way. Besides, in the Firefox version of the Last Pass extension, it clearly states that it connects many types of data including your IP address, location information, Operating System, language, and: **"unique device identifiers and other diagnostic data"**. Last Pass even uses Google Analytics which is subject to Google's private policy. Furthermore, it uses cookies to track you for login, preferences, advertisements, and security purposes. The Last Pass addon also determine's the user's location through a variety of methods. While it may be impossible to remember passwords, it would be easier for websites to track you and the whole point of Tor is to be anonymous, which is being eliminated through the use of Last Pass. The answer is clear, don't use LassPass and avoid addons always while using the Tor browser if possible. Use another application which only stores your passwords locally. This answer is just a summary of the other answers and I just wanted to include in detail about using Last Pass.

**TL;DR:** Last Pass collects numerous data about its users and can expose your anonymity while using the Tor browser - just use an application locally to store your passwords. If you really need for some reason to use Last Pass and it isn't working, it could be some glitch. Try reinstalling the extension or try installing it in the Firefox browser. If it works fine in the Firefox browser, then the issue is with using that specific addon on Tor. Also, try updating the Tor browser, as that could be an issue too.